# changing your answer to match someone else's

Tags: discussion, answers

Following sequence of events occurred on [using brackets with javascript import syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax/31096635#comment50212851_31096635):

1. First answer was posted, but was wrong.
2. I posted my answer, which was correct :-)
3. First answer was then modified to match my answer (with attribution)

Meanwhile, the first answer got a total of four up-votes, some from when it was still wrong. My answer has one. There is no accepted answer yet.

I guess this falls into the "grin-and-bear-it-and-move-on" category? What are the ethics of essentially posting a different answer which is still timestamped with the time of an earlier, incorrect answer? Is this flaggable?

Comment: Flag as what? "This user stole my fame and glory, ban him right away?"